# How to assign sample_weights in sklearn.cluster DBSCAN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dbscan

I'm using DBSCAN to find clusters of pixel values of an RGB image.

`db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)`

where, `X` is an `N x 3` matrix. Each row of `X` contains RGB triplets.

Now, I want to assign weights to pixel values as a function of distance from the center of the image.
And this is the function I'm using:

`score =  1 / (1 + math.exp(-a * distance)) # a = 0.001`

I compute `weight_matrix` filled with `score` as above

Next I did this:

`db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X,y=None, sample_weight=weight_matrix)`

where, length of the `weight_matrix` array is equal to the number of rows in `X`.

But I get the following error:

`TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'`

So I tried doing it like this:

`db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X, sample_weight=weight_matrix)`

Now I get this error:

`TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'`

I think I'm passing the arguments incorrectly, but couldn't be sure. My scikit-learn version is 0.14.0.

Comment: Maybe you have an old version installed?

Comment: Taking a look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN it seems fine. One thing I wonder is what `weight_matrix` is for you. You say that it should have the same number of `rows` as `X`, but it `weight_matrix` should be an array of `length` equal to the number of rows in `X`. Also check the version that you have, it may not be the latest.

Comment: @ZWiki: Thanks for theinfo on size of ``weight_matrix`` array. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using scikit-learn v <= 0.15, as this is the last version where DBSCAN had fit of form

```
fit(X)
```

since 0.16 it is

```
fit(X, y=None, sample_weight=None)
```

Simply update your scikit-learn to 0.16 or 0.17.X

Comment: Then ask a separate question showing what exactly is happening, what do you mean by crushes

Comment: When the DBSCAN().fit() method is called. It says "Killed" and exits.